# Creating serial number for unique entries in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to assign same serial number for all same Submission_Ids under one Batch_number. Could some one please help me figure this out?

```r
Submission_Id <- c(619295,619295,619295,619295,619296,619296,619296,619296,619296,556921,556921,559254,647327,647327,647327,646040,646040,646040,646040,646040,64604)
Batch_No <- (633,633,633,633,633,633,633,633,633,633,633,633,634,634,634,650,650,650,650,650,650)
```

Expected result

```r
Sl.No <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is creating run-length IDs with `data.table::rleid(Submission_Id)` `grouped_by(Batch_No)`. We can use this inside 'dplyr'. To show this I created a `tibble()` with both given vectors `Batch_Id` and `Submission_Id`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

dat <- tibble(Submission_Id = Submission_Id,
              Batch_No = Batch_No)

dat %>% 
  group_by(Batch_No) %>% 
  mutate(S1.No = data.table::rleid(Submission_Id)) 

#> # A tibble: 21 x 3
#> # Groups:   Batch_No [3]
#>    Submission_Id Batch_No S1.No
#>            <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
#>  1        619295      633     1
#>  2        619295      633     1
#>  3        619295      633     1
#>  4        619295      633     1
#>  5        619296      633     2
#>  6        619296      633     2
#>  7        619296      633     2
#>  8        619296      633     2
#>  9        619296      633     2
#> 10        556921      633     3
#> # ... with 11 more rows
```

The original data

```r
Submission_Id <- c(619295,619295,619295,619295,619296,619296,619296,619296,619296,556921,556921,559254,647327,647327,647327,646040,646040,646040,646040,646040,64604)
Batch_No <- c(633,633,633,633,633,633,633,633,633,633,633,633,634,634,634,650,650,650,650,650,650)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>